# Where is the VFR Day certification List

Tags: faa-regulations, part-91-operations

Where can I find the VfR day certification instruments and equipment for which my aircraft was certificated?

Is this 91.205? I looked through the POH it mentioned Part 91.

Is it saying that the aircraft is only airworthy IF those instruments are operative apart from ADs,Maintenance times?

If The instruments are inoperative then the airplane cannot fly?

But if the instruments are not listed in 91.205 and does not have an AD

Would I just use a placard to indicate it’s inoperative and make a notice to maintenance?

Is that the full procedure?

Comment: Yes. Refer to 91.205(b) for VFR (day).  Part 91.213 addresses Inoperative equipment. transponder and ADS-B out equipment may also be required. Please narrow your focus as ASE is based on one question at a time, not 4 or 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need everything in 91.205(b), but your POH should have an equipment list. Anything marked as required in that equipment list is *also* required, as is anything listed as required on the Type Certificate Data Sheet for the aircraft type. These requirements may be altered by alterations to the aircraft- for instance, if you replace your vacuum instruments with a pair of Garmin G5, the STC permits you to remove the vacuum system. Airworthiness Directives may also add required equipment.

Once you've determined that equipment is not required, you need to disable it and placard it as inoperative or have it removed per 14 CFR § 91.213(d)(3).

The above assumes you are not authorized to use a Minimum Equipmemt List for that aircraft. If you are, you have to follow that.

Finally, you can apply for a special flight permit to operate the plane while you are lacking some required equipment. This is frequently used to transport planes to somewhere they can be repaired.

Comment: Ok so I Should follow the equipment list. That should be the comprehensive equipment list in my POH? And all of the instruments listed in the Comprehensive list should be apart of the TCDS? In the event that I replace an instrument such as the vacuum system, The STC and the AD would require meant to  That would permit me to remove the Vacuum system.

Comment: Ok so I Should follow the equipment list. and that should be the comprehensive equipment list in my POH? 2. All of the instruments listed in the Comprehensive list should be apart of the TCDS? 3.In the event that I do have to replace an instrument such as the vacuum system, The STC and the AD would may be required to remove the system entirely.   Lastly, if the equip is not apart of the Comprehensive list and 91.205 and it is inoperative, I would label it inoperative?

Comment: You need equipment if it is listed as required in *any* of 91.205, the POH, the TCDS, or any applicable ADs. STCs can remove a requirement, essentially amending the type certificate.